# Custom Modification to a Highchart's Pie Chart

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts

I want to create a pie chart with 5 slices. Each slice represents a company. I want to have an invisible straight line in the center of each slice. Whenever the user will click on any area inside the slice, it will draw a black dot (or an HTML icon ) on that point in a straight line.

I have attached a rough sketch of what I want to achieve. The red lines will be the invisible red lines as shown in the sketch.

So it's like scoring each company by clicking on its slice. If the user clicks on any area at the end of the slice, the score will be 100% (Company D in sketch) and it will draw a black dot at the end of the straight line in that slice. Similarly, if it clicks slightly before the end of the slice (say 80%, Company B), it will draw a black dot on a straight line at 80%. I will also want to collect all the clicked point percentages of all 5 companies at the end to process further calculations in my HTML code.

[image]

I have attached my code:

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    plotBackgroundColor: null,
    plotBorderWidth: null,
    plotShadow: false,
    type: 'pie'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Pie Chart'
  },
  tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>',
    enabled: false
  },
  accessibility: {
    point: {
      valueSuffix: '%'
    }
  },
  plotOptions: {
    pie: {
      innerSize: 50,
      // slicedOffset: 10,
      // allowPointSelect: true,
      cursor: 'pointer',
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        distance: -60,
        // format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %'
        // format: '{point.percentage:.1f} %'
        format: '{point.name}'

      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Brands',
    colorByPoint: true,
    enableMouseTracking: false,
    data: [{
        name: 'Company A',
        y: 1,
        color: '#ffdb04'

      }, {
        name: 'Company B',
        y: 1,
        color: '#ffdb04'

      }, {
        name: 'Company C',
        y: 1,
        color: '#ffdb04'

      }, {
        name: 'Company D',
        y: 1,
        color: '#ffdb04'

      }, {
        name: 'Company E',
        y: 1,
        color: '#ffdb04',

      }


    ]
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<figure class="highcharts-figure">
  <div id="container"></div>
</figure>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You can use [SVG renderer](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer) and render [lines](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#path) and [buttons](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#button) (looks like dots). 

I don't quite have an idea how to make the position reading reflect the ranking. I still have to think about how to do it, get back to me if you want I'll prepare a demo for it.